# Dynamically setting Where condition in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, where-clause

I am looking for a method where I need to have conditions on my WHERE clause change dynamically based on the data.

Please find the mock data for my scenario.

```
 -----------------------------------
  ConditionID        ConditionName
 -----------------------------------
  1                  N/A
  2                  Over
  3                  Under

  --------------------------------------------------------------
   ID        Amount        ThresholdAmount        ConditionID
  --------------------------------------------------------------
   1         90            100                    3
   2         190           100                    2
   3         90            100                    2
   4         190           100                    3
   5         90            100                    1
```

I need to compare the [Amount] against the [ThresholdAmount] based on the [ConditionID]. For example if the condition is 'Over' then the [Amount] should be over the [ThresholdAmount] and if not satisfied then the record should be filtered out.

NOTE: I am just looking if there is any better approach than mine.

My Approach:

```
WHERE
    1 =   CASE 
            WHEN ConditionName = 'OVER' THEN
                CASE WHEN ([Amount] >= [ThresholdAmount]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            WHEN ConditionName = 'UNDER' THEN 
                CASE WHEN ([Amount] <= [ThresholdAmount]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            WHEN ConditionName =  'N/A' THEN
                1
          END
```

Thanks,
Prakazz

Comment: Edit your question and show your "answer".  Why should anyone bother trying to help, if they are just going to arrive at what you have already done.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using the word "Dynamically" wrong here, what you mean is not really dynamic. Search for `dynamic sql` to get a feel for the difference.

It's usually best to avoid case expressions in the `where` clause. Your `where` clause can be rewritten as:

```
WHERE       (ConditionName = 'OVER' AND [Amount] >= [ThresholdAmount])
        OR  (ConditionName = 'UNDER' AND [Amount] <= [ThresholdAmount])
        OR  ConditionName =  'N/A'
```

By the way, you mention "if the condition is 'Over' then the [Amount] should be over the [ThresholdAmount]", but in your code you check whether `Amount` is 'over' **or equal** to `ThresholdAmount`. I followed what your code does.

I also extended your assumption that the database is case-insensitive.